# How can I check for a string match AND an empty file in the same if/then bash script statement?

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I'm writing a simple bash script to do the following:

1) Check two files (foo1 and foo2).

2) If foo1 is different from foo2 and foo1 NOT blank, send an email.

3) If foo1 is the same as foo2... or foo1 is blank... do nothing.

The blank condition is what's confusing me.  Here's what I've got to start with:

```
diff --brief <(sort ./foo1) <(sort ./foo2) >/dev/null
comp_value=$?

if [ $comp_value -ne 0 ]
then
        mail -s "Alert" bob@bob.com <./alertfoo

fi
```

Obviously this doesn't check for blank contents.  Any thoughts on how to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the test's `-s` operator to check whether the file is empty, and `cmp` is generally the simplest way to check files for equality (note that you can use a command directly in an `if` statement as a simpler alternative to comparing its exit status with 0). I'm keeping the bit where you sort the two files before comparing them; if that's not needed, just use the two files directly as arguments to `cmp`.

```
if [ -s ./foo1 ] && ! cmp -q <(sort ./foo1) <(sort ./foo2); then
    ...
```

You can read the above as: "if ./foo1 is not empty (`[ -s ... ]`) AND (`&&`) the sorted forms of ./foo1 and ./foo2 are NOT (`!`) the same (`cmp`)".

Comment: Perfect.  That's EXACTLY what I needed to know. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use -s to check if a file is empty:

```
if [[ -s $FILE ]] ; then
echo "$FILE has data."
else
echo "$FILE is empty."
fi
```

If you want to know whether a string is empty or not, use the option -z to check if empty:

```
STRING="test"
if [[ -n "$STRING" ]]; then
    echo "String is not empty"
fi
```

or -n to check if not empty:

```
STRING=""
if [[ -z "$STRING" ]]; then
    echo "String is empty"
fi
```

Comment: Thanks.  How would I combine to two searches? So essentially write an if/then statement to say "If file is not empty AND if blah blah"...

Comment: As documented in `test(1)` use `-a` to connect to expressions with an AND operation.